# Python- scipy.interp2d throwing runtime warning about knots

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to use scipy.interp2d to build an interpolation function based off a data set I have, using Python 2.7.  However, Python keeps throwing this warning whenever I run it:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack_impl.py:975: RuntimeWarning: No more knots can be added because the additional knot would
coincide with an old one. Probable cause: s too small or too large
a weight to an inaccurate data point. (fp>s)
    kx,ky=1,1 nx,ny=18,4 m=106 fp=1355.885984 s=0.000000
  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))
```

Similar warnings occur if I use cubic or quintic instead of linear.

The data itself looks something like this:

```html
x y z
400 0.1 24.5525361598
500 0.1 30.3102509102
700 0.1 36.9604444013
800 0.1 38.8662807180
900 0.1 40.2185588452
1000 0.1 41.2610946000
...

1300 1 50.7991409954
1400 1 50.7991411538
1500 1 50.7991416176
1600 1 50.7991433783
....
1100 10 51.3296099771
1200 10 51.3296099928
1300 10 51.3296100395
1400 10 51.3296101921
1500 10 51.3296108783
1600 10 51.3296145611
...
2500 100 52.2442339828
2600 100 52.3526243978
2700 100 52.4918053348
2800 100 52.6511782816
```

I've read elsewhere that this may be a bug in scipy.interp2d-- if so, is there any work around?  And if it's that there's a problem in my data, how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `s` is too small or a weight is too large.  Have you tried a larger `s`?  The documentation says:

```
s : float, optional
    A non-negative smoothing factor.  If weights correspond
    to the inverse of the standard-deviation of the errors in z,
    then a good s-value should be found in the range
    ``(m-sqrt(2*m),m+sqrt(2*m))`` where m=len(x).
```

Toward the bottom of the scipy docs, it says

> The interpolator is constructed by bisplrep, with a smoothing factor
>   of 0. If more control over smoothing is needed, bisplrep should be
>   used directly.

Then use `bisplev` to do the interpolation: `bisplev(xs, ys, tck, ...)` where xs, ys are the coords in interpolate and tck is the output from `bisplrep`.

Comment: How would I go about changing the s? I didn't think scipy.interp2d had a parameter for that.

Comment: Sorry, I looked at line 975 in the _fitpack_impl.py source code, to see what function was called and looked at the doc string.  I added a reference to the scipy docs to my answer - it says use `bisplrep` which lets you set `s`.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Will that return an interpolation function, though? It looks like it just returns the surface values (I think--I honestly know nothing about the actual mathematics involved in this kind of interpolation).

Comment: Ah, awesome.  Thank you so much!